# Typeahead Bloodhound - Filter

Tags: filtering, typeahead.js, bloodhound

My index contains the word **dog** how can i also find this entry if i type **dogs**? I would find all parts of the word 'dogs','dog','do' to a min length of 2 or 3 chars

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Bloodhound, but what you're talking about here is called [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), and it seems like the kind of thing that you could do using the `datumTokenizer` and the `queryTokenizer`.

There are stemmers for most languages of varying quality, but I think the one most people are using for English these days is the [Snowball Stemmer](http://snowball.tartarus.org/). There are a number of implementations in JavaScript floating around.

In general for things to work properly you'll want to stem *both* the uer's query and the results.